# create column with year

Tags: 2013, list

I am creating column in list where user gets to choose year

```
string[] years = { "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2023", "2024", "2025", "2026" };
        AddYear(list, "AgeYear", SPFieldType.Choice, false, years);


private void AddYear(SPList list, string fieldname, SPFieldType sPFieldType, bool visibleaction, string[] param)
    {
            string spFieldName = list.Fields.Add(fieldname, sPFieldType, visibleaction);
            SPFieldChoice fieldYear = (SPFieldChoice) list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(spFieldName);
            fieldChoice.Choices.AddRange(param);


            fieldYear.Update();
        }
```

But its now limited to year 2026. This is not good solution. Is there any better solution to choose only years. Dont wish to select previous year before 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will result in an array of strings that has ten years in it, from the current year to 10 years forward. Adjust the numbers in the for loop to your requirements.

I haven't been able to test it, so apologies for any syntactical mistakes.

```
List<string> years = new List<string>();
int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    years.Add(Convert.ToString(currentYear + i));
}

AddYear(list, "AgeYear", SPFieldType.Choice, false, years.ToArray());

private void AddYear(SPList list, string fieldname, SPFieldType sPFieldType, bool visibleaction, string[] param)
{
    string spFieldName = list.Fields.Add(fieldname, sPFieldType, visibleaction);
    SPFieldChoice fieldYear = (SPFieldChoice) list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(spFieldName);
    fieldChoice.Choices.AddRange(param);

    fieldYear.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom form and the requirement is just to display future years, and required to store it in any form then, below solution should fit your requirement best:

Create origional column as Single line of text (Supposed Named: Year)
Create a html textbox control in your form (Supposed Named: YearPicker), hide the origional control from form.
Use jqueryui reference in ur page

write a custom jquery code:

```
YearPicker.datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy',
        minDate: new Date(<<Provide minimum year you want>>),
        maxDate: new Date(<<Provide Maximum year you want>>)
    })
```

on change event of YearPicker, capture the selected value, and set it to the hidden control and you are done.

Hope this completes your search.

**Regards:
Gaurravs**